# Rundeck UI plugin : How to access property values from fromframeowrk.properties

Tags: user-interface, plugins, properties, zip, rundeck

I want to access a property value present in framework.properties file
How can I get it in rundeck plugin type UI

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible, check the documentation: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/11-ui-plugins.html and an example: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/ui-plugin-examples to know what you can do with a UI Plugin.